# Getting error while doing react-native link

Tags: android, react-native, native-base

I am creating project in react native for android and tried to install `native-base` using the following command `npm install native-base --save`. After that when I am linking the library using `react-native link` I am getting error as follow.

```
rnpm-install ERR! ERRPACKAGEJSON No package found. Are you sure this is a React Native project?

Cannot read property '_text' of undefined

TypeError: Cannot read property '_text' of undefined
    at SAXParser.parser_text [as ontext] (/home/codism-8/NewReactWorkSpace/NamazTiming/node_modules/xmldoc/lib/xmldoc.js:235:39)
    at emit (/home/codism-8/NewReactWorkSpace/NamazTiming/node_modules/xmldoc/node_modules/sax/lib/sax.js:639:35)
    at closeText (/home/codism-8/NewReactWorkSpace/NamazTiming/node_modules/xmldoc/node_modules/sax/lib/sax.js:649:26)
    at emitNode (/home/codism-8/NewReactWorkSpace/NamazTiming/node_modules/xmldoc/node_modules/sax/lib/sax.js:643:26)
    at SAXParser.write (/home/codism-8/NewReactWorkSpace/NamazTiming/node_modules/xmldoc/node_modules/sax/lib/sax.js:1195:15)
    at new XmlDocument (/home/codism-8/NewReactWorkSpace/NamazTiming/node_modules/xmldoc/lib/xmldoc.js:199:15)
    at readManifest (/home/codism-8/NewReactWorkSpace/NamazTiming/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/core/android/readManifest.js:20:10)
    at Object.projectConfigAndroid [as projectConfig] (/home/codism-8/NewReactWorkSpace/NamazTiming/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/core/android/index.js:41:20)
    at Object.keys.forEach.key (/home/codism-8/NewReactWorkSpace/NamazTiming/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/core/index.js:101:36)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
```

I followed this documentation http://docs.nativebase.io/docs/GetStarted.html. I am not getting what is the problem. Please help

Package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "native-base": "^2.12.0",
    "react": "16.6.3",
    "react-native": "^0.57.7",
    "react-native-flash-message": "^0.1.10",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.5.3",
    "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^6.0.0",
    "react-native-navigation": "^2.8.0",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^1.3.2",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^6.0.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
  },
```

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you are running the command in the correct folder, because the link command is unable to find your `package.json`?

Comment: yes I am in the correct folder

Comment: please help bro what is the problem

Comment: share your project exiting path, your node server screenshot and if possible also share your react-native and native-based version in your question.In which Directory you have fire react-native link command?

Comment: Sorry for late see the updated one

Comment: @Andrew please help me I stuck here.

Comment: @ParasKorat help me to remove out of this

Comment: @AhteshamShah for security, it also tries to launch `npm audit fix`, as reported at the end of the `npm install`

Answer (score 3):

1-Make sure you've done the `npm install native-base --save` in the project directory
2- Try `npm i` to fix the problems with dependencies, then command`react-native run-android` to make sure your dependencies and "node_modules" folder work properly and project can run.
If you don't have 'android' or 'ios' folder you can use command `react-native eject`, then link the packages.
3- Write the command `react-native link native-base`, this command links exactly native-base package with react native.
However I recommend you to mostly link the packages manually.
You can also try previous version of native base, like v `2.10.0`.

Comment: the app is working properly after `react -native run-android`

Comment: did you link with command `react-native link native-base` or `react-native link?` are you using react-native or expo?

Comment: yes, I tried `react-native link native-base` got same error and I am using react-native. Where is the problem

Comment: try uninstalling the package and installing previous versions of native base, like 2.10.0 which is a more tested version.

Comment: the problem is with _text. Did you make a folder or dependencies configuration named _text or like that? If yes, delete it.

Comment: take a look, there is something named _text in your project, I can see it in the screenshot you've sent.

Comment: its somewhere in node_modules/xmldoc/lib/xmldoc.js not anywhere in my code

Comment: Delete node_modules, then `npm i` for last try. It must be a bug or something.

Comment: I'm using react-native, I don't use expo

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @AmirGorji @parashKorat for helping me. For me, this problem was coming because I have removed `android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"` from the manifest file. When I put it again the `react-native link` is working. I removed it because after adding my icons it was showing the error of missing a round icon, for temporary I removed that.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.namaztiming">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>

    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
      <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I don't know is it a proper solution or not but in my case, it solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue today and what I did was ran these commands to clean the gradle for the project.

1- Go to the root directory of the project.

2- Run `cd android`

3- Run `gradlew clean`

4- Run `cd..`

and then run the `link` commands

Answer (score 0):

Since react 0.69 linking is not working. The alternative is to install react-native-assets, but this gives me errors with react-native 0.69.4. So I decided to install manually.

For iOS:

Step 1 : Add/Remove fonts to “Resources” folder in xcode project

[image]

Note : Just Drag the fonts in xcode “Resources” folder and check “Copy items if needed” . Add to target should be your project.

if files are copied correctly you can see the files in “Copy bundle resources” in “Build phases” tab

[image]

Step 2 : Add/Remove fonts in info.plist files in xcode project with key “Fonts provided by application”

[image]

For Android:

Step 1 : Add/Remove fonts to android project in following directory

android/app/src/main/assets/

[image]